# Gsub command to replace all spaces with a comma and space, (", "), except after certain words with R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a data.frame with a column containing California counties in each cell separated by a space. I would like to add a comma and space after each one, however I can't just gsub every space into a comma and space, (i.e. gsub("\s",",\s",text)), as some counties in California have two names, (e.g. Los Angeles, San Francisco, etc.)

Fortunately, the two-word counties all have common first words so I'd like to write a gsub that preserves the space in those counties without adding a comma. I've attached example data as well as what I'd like the final form to look like. For instance, with this data, I'd like to add a comma and space except after "El", "San" and "Del".

Example data:

```
c("Lassen Modoc Nevada Plumas Shasta Sierra Siskiyou Butte Placer", 
"Del Norte Humboldt Trinity Mendocino Sonoma", "Glenn Sutter Tehama Yuba Butte Colusa", 
"Lake Napa Yolo Colusa Sonoma Solano", "Madera Amador Tuolumne Calaveras Mariposa Mono Alpine El Dorado Placer", 
"El Dorado Placer Sacramento", "Sacramento Yolo", "Sacramento", 
"Sacramento San Joaquin", "Marin Sonoma")
```

Desired output:

```
c("Lassen, Modoc, Nevada, Plumas, Shasta, Sierra, Siskiyou, Butte, Placer", 
  "Del Norte, Humboldt, Trinity, Mendocino, Sonoma", "Glenn, Sutter, Tehama, Yuba, Butte, Colusa", 
  "Lake, Napa, Yolo, Colusa, Sonoma, Solano", "Madera, Amador, Tuolumne, Calaveras, Mariposa, Mono, Alpine, El Dorado, Placer", 
  "El Dorado, Placer, Sacramento", "Sacramento, Yolo", "Sacramento", 
  "Sacramento, San Joaquin", "Marin, Sonoma")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you know you are only looking for California counties, one "easy" way is just to replace only spaces that occur after a California county. To get that regex, I just concatenated the CA county names together with `|` and added a space. The `gsub` will replace any county name followed by a space with the same county name (`\\1`), a comma, and a space.

```r
ca_regex <- "(Los Angeles|San Diego|Orange|Riverside|San Bernardino|Santa Clara|Alameda|Sacramento|Contra Costa|Fresno|Kern|San Francisco|Ventura|San Mateo|San Joaquin|Stanislaus|Sonoma|Tulare|Santa Barbara|Solano|Monterey|Placer|San Luis Obispo|Santa Cruz|Merced|Marin|Butte|Yolo|El Dorado|Imperial|Shasta|Madera|Kings|Napa|Humboldt|Nevada|Sutter|Mendocino|Yuba|Lake|Tehama|San Benito|Tuolumne|Calaveras|Siskiyou|Amador|Lassen|Glenn|Del Norte|Colusa|Plumas|Inyo|Mariposa|Mono|Trinity|Modoc|Sierra|Alpine) "

input <- c(
  "Lassen Modoc Nevada Plumas Shasta Sierra Siskiyou Butte Placer",
  "Del Norte Humboldt Trinity Mendocino Sonoma", "Glenn Sutter Tehama Yuba Butte Colusa",
  "Lake Napa Yolo Colusa Sonoma Solano", "Madera Amador Tuolumne Calaveras Mariposa Mono Alpine El Dorado Placer",
  "El Dorado Placer Sacramento", "Sacramento Yolo", "Sacramento",
  "Sacramento San Joaquin", "Marin Sonoma"
)

gsub(ca_regex, "\\1, ", input)
#>  [1] "Lassen, Modoc, Nevada, Plumas, Shasta, Sierra, Siskiyou, Butte, Placer"        
#>  [2] "Del Norte, Humboldt, Trinity, Mendocino, Sonoma"                               
#>  [3] "Glenn, Sutter, Tehama, Yuba, Butte, Colusa"                                    
#>  [4] "Lake, Napa, Yolo, Colusa, Sonoma, Solano"                                      
#>  [5] "Madera, Amador, Tuolumne, Calaveras, Mariposa, Mono, Alpine, El Dorado, Placer"
#>  [6] "El Dorado, Placer, Sacramento"                                                 
#>  [7] "Sacramento, Yolo"                                                              
#>  [8] "Sacramento"                                                                    
#>  [9] "Sacramento, San Joaquin"                                                       
#> [10] "Marin, Sonoma"
```

If you want, you can use a negative lookbehind (`(?<!)`) to use a shorter pattern. This one takes only the prefix words from the CA county list and will only replace spaces that don't come after one of them. I think this is a little harder to reason about, though, and harder to come up with (e.g. on first posting I forgot about the two-spaced San Luis Obispo County)

```r
gsub("(?<!Los|San|Santa|Contra|El|Del|Luis) ", ", ", input, perl = TRUE)
#>  [1] "Lassen, Modoc, Nevada, Plumas, Shasta, Sierra, Siskiyou, Butte, Placer"        
#>  [2] "Del Norte, Humboldt, Trinity, Mendocino, Sonoma"                               
#>  [3] "Glenn, Sutter, Tehama, Yuba, Butte, Colusa"                                    
#>  [4] "Lake, Napa, Yolo, Colusa, Sonoma, Solano"                                      
#>  [5] "Madera, Amador, Tuolumne, Calaveras, Mariposa, Mono, Alpine, El Dorado, Placer"
#>  [6] "El Dorado, Placer, Sacramento"                                                 
#>  [7] "Sacramento, Yolo"                                                              
#>  [8] "Sacramento"                                                                    
#>  [9] "Sacramento, San Joaquin"                                                       
#> [10] "Marin, Sonoma"
```

Comment: If you use the second option, note that I just changed it to handle San Luis Obispo.

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub('(\\w{4,}) ', '\\1, ', vec)

 [1] "Lassen, Modoc, Nevada, Plumas, Shasta, Sierra, Siskiyou, Butte, Placer"        
 [2] "Del Norte, Humboldt, Trinity, Mendocino, Sonoma"                               
 [3] "Glenn, Sutter, Tehama, Yuba, Butte, Colusa"                                    
 [4] "Lake, Napa, Yolo, Colusa, Sonoma, Solano"                                      
 [5] "Madera, Amador, Tuolumne, Calaveras, Mariposa, Mono, Alpine, El Dorado, Placer"
 [6] "El Dorado, Placer, Sacramento"                                                 
 [7] "Sacramento, Yolo"                                                              
 [8] "Sacramento"                                                                    
 [9] "Sacramento, San Joaquin"                                                       
[10] "Marin, Sonoma"
```

Comment: This is fine for OP's input set but will split Santa Clara and Contra Costa, since their first words have more than 4 letters.